# Why does uniq think あい and いあ are the same?

Tags: bash, sort, uniq

I'm trying to find duplicates in files, by using:

```
sort myfile | uniq -d
```

I noticed that uniq seems to dislike Japanese characters for some reason. For example, if I have a file:

```
あい
いあ
```

Then

```
sort myfile | uniq -d
```

Prints

```
あい
```

Why is this? Some kind of locale problem?

Edit: [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17198/where-has-my-uniq-or-sort-u-line-gone-with-some-unicode-characters) was marked as a duplicate. While the underlying problem (strcoll) is the same, this question is fundamentally different. Also, the accepted answer to that question isn't the same as the answer to this question, which is to change locale to C.

Comment: What is your locale setting, please?

Comment: In short: yes, it's a locale issue; no, it's not a misconfiguration from you, it's a choice made in the collation definitions of the locale you're using.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=C sort myfile | LC_COLLATE=C uniq -d` should work, however. I can reproduce this with glibc & GNU `sort`/`uniq`.

Comment: Yes, you all are correct. It was a locale problem, my locale was LC_ALL=ja_JP.utf8 and changing it temporarily to LC_ALL=C worked.

Comment: @Agargara Please add this as an answer for future readers.

Comment: @dr01 I would, but the ever vigilant stack gestapo have marked this as a duplicate. Hopefully future readers can figure it out even though the duplicate is a different problem with a different solution.

Comment: @Agargara I voted to reopen, the question is now reopened and you can post your answer.

Comment: @dr01 I added an answer, I hope that covers correctly the comments, please review it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the locale is en_US.utf8 (as one example), both strings seem equal:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "いあ" "あい" "いあ" "あい"
いあ
あい
いあ
あい

$ LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 bash -c '
    printf "%s\n" "いあ" "あい" "いあ" "あい" |
    sort | 
    uniq '
いあ
```

If, however, the language is changed to ja_JP, all seems to work correctly:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=ja_JP.utf8 bash -c '
    printf "%s\n" "いあ" "あい" "いあ" "あい" | 
    sort | 
    uniq '
あい
いあ
```

It is interesting to note that (in this case) a C locale also work:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C bash -c '
    printf "%s\n" "いあ" "あい" "いあ" "あい" |
    sort |
    uniq '
あい
いあ
```

That only goes to show that en_US is missing the collate order for some code points.