# What's the best way to sort?

Tags: text-processing, sort

I do text manipulation a lot, and one of the operations I use frequently is sorting - often removing any duplicates as well.

So I normally use the commands `sort` or `sort -u` either from command line or in scripts, macros, etc - if I'm not working in **LibreOffice** **Writer** or **Calc**, of course (which unfortunately don't have an option to remove duplicates while sorting, or I don't know ;-)

Now I have a plain text file containing a large collection of symbols, emoticons, shapes, lines, non-standard ASCII letters and numbers, etc. with many duplicates.

It was easy to convert them a into one character per line text.

However, sorting and removing duplicates apparently is not as simple as one would think:

Using the command `sort -u file.txt > file-sorted.txt` unfortunately reduces the 2078 lines down to just 359, removing about a thousand unique characters I guess - I can see that there are many many that are filtered out in error.

So my conclusion is that `sort -u command` is **only good for standard alphanumeric characters**.

Any ideas and suggestions?

**PS:** Here is a sample text of 40 characters from the file I'm trying to process:

```
ღ ❂ ◕ ⊕ Θ o O ♋ ☯ ⊙ ◎ ๑ ☜ ☞ ♨ ☎ ☏ ۩ ۞ ♬ ✖ ɔ ½ ' ‿ ' * ᴗ * ◕ ‿ ◕ ❊ ᴗ ❊ . ᴗ . ᵒ ᴗ
```

There are only a few duplicates here but although `sort` command processes the text with a few issues, but without any loss, both `sort -u` and `uniq` have exactly the same output, cutting it down to 11 with many characters wiped out.

Comment: Can you provide file samples? What do you want to achieve? Of course sorting with additional removing duplicates is not easy. Sort command uses mergesort algorithm, which it rather fast one.

Comment: Possibly related: [Where has my `uniq` or `sort -u` line gone, with some unicode characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17198/where-has-my-uniq-or-sort-u-line-gone-with-some-unicode-characters)

Comment: Do you get the same output as sort if you pipe the file through `sort | uniq`?

Comment: @mrc02_kr Thanks; please see my PS note above.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks; please see my PS note above.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. Although I cannot understand very well what's going on there, it seems I'm right in my suspicion that such non-standard unicode characters, symbols, etc. are probably beyond the capabilities of `sort` and `uniq` :-( I wonder if there's any alternative other than `msort` which cannot deal with duplicates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something with proper Unicode support, such as Python:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sorted(set(c for l in sys.stdin.readlines() for c in l.split()))))' < bar
'
*
.
O
o
½
ɔ
Θ
۞
۩
๑
ღ
ᴗ
ᵒ
‿
⊕
⊙
◎
◕
☎
☏
☜
☞
☯
♋
♨
♬
✖
❂
❊
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print(len(set(c for l in sys.stdin.readlines() for c in l.split())))' < bar
30
```

Comment: Great! But ( as an average user ; -) how can I apply this script to a file please? Replace "bar" at the end with the file name? Actually I intend to make a nautilus/nemo script out of this, if I can.

Comment: @Sadi Yes. The python command is reading from stdin, so you can pick your favourite way to send files to the stdin of a command. Or you could loop over arguments in Python itself.

Comment: I should have tried it first ;-) It works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the record: This gave me a file with 933 lines, which looks more like it, with only one exception, as far as I can see: two zeros. However, sorting is not very smart. For instance, emoticons, number in circles, etc. are scattered all over the place. But I've managed to get closer to perfection when I copied it to LibreOffice Calc and sorted them - which grouped all emoticons together, and sorted all sorts of numbers in circles, etc. quite smartly :-)

Comment: @Sadi Oh, yeah, the output is *unsorted*. Note that I just used the `set` data structure to get unique elements, I didn't bother with sorting. I updated the first command to do some sorting, but I'm not sure if the output is what you want.

Comment: Wov! Now even the duplicate 0 is gone, and it also looks better than LO Calc! Thanks a lot...

Comment: May I also ask which part to take out in order to sort unique lines only, i.e. without replacing all spacing with line breaks?

Comment: @Sadi If splitting the lines is not needed, then it's considerably simpler: `python3 -c 'import sys; print("".join(sorted(set(sys.stdin))))'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think from now on I'll use this simpler version as a better alternative to the command `sort -u` ( having passed a though test with flying colors :-) And the first one as a script to create word lists out of text files :-)